# NSDate (without time) from UTC date string

Tags: nsdate

I have looked at almost every post on here regarding NSDate conversion but have not been successful in resolving my issue.

**Background**:
I am wanting to simply compare NSDate (without time) values when rendering values within my CalendarView. However, when I convert the ISO date from the server it actually returns the previous date due to what I guess is GMT offset values. However, I just want to honor the Year, Month, Day which was passed from the server.

**Code**:

Value from the server: `date: "2014-09-26T00:00:00.000Z"`

Objective-C code to convert to NSDate. I am using [Soffes library](https://github.com/soffes/iso8601) to handle the ISO date conversion.

`NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithISO8601String:myDate timeZone:&timezone usingCalendar:nil];
    NSDate *dateWithoutTime = [NSDate dateWithOutTime:date];`

Code to return date without time:

`NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];`

**Current Results**:

ISO date from string

`po date 2014-09-26 00:00:00 +0000`

Date without time

`po dateWithoutTime 2014-09-25 06:00:00 +0000`

Any suggestions on how I can still honor the Year, Month, Day passed from the server?